# Ошибка в рекурсивной функции Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, рекурсия

Вот программа, она должна считать все последовательности букв от `a` до `s`
Когда я ввожу `d` должно вывести 4 а выводит 0.

В чем ошибка?

```
ans = 0
otv = 0
alph = list(set("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"))
alph.sort()
isin = set()
s = input()
def pereb(sps):
    global ans
    global otv
    global isin
    global s
    global alph
    if len(sps) == len(s):
        if "".join(sps) not in isin:
            if "".join(sps) == s:
                ans += 1
                otv = ans
                isin.add("".join(sps))
                print("#")
            else:
                ans += 1
                isin.add("".join(sps))
                print("##")
        else:
            for i in alph:
                sps.append(i)
                ans += 1
                print("###")
                pereb(n, sps)
                sps.pop()
pereb([])
print(otv)
```

Comment: Уточните условие и приведите пример!

Comment: Что такое считать последовательности букв? По какой логике получается число 4? Пока мало что понятно

Comment: Последовательность букв - строка, например abv , dfg, dhfkghdjkfh
По логике a, b, c, d - 4 последовательности

Comment: Программа - решение задачи
Как известно, все имена в Байтландии одинаковой длины и состоят только из маленьких латинских букв; при рождении ребёнку выдается лексиграфически наименьшее свободное имя.
Этот очаровательный малыш — самый юный гражданин Байтландии, и зовут его S.
Определите, сколько же людей живёт в Байтландии? Байтландцы давно победили смерть, поэтому все родившиеся люди сейчас живы и являются гражданами Байтландии.1

Примеры:
d - 4
bc - 29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы вводите 'd', то это является значением переменной `s`, а `len(s)`, соответственно, равно 1.

При этом `sps` - пустой список `[]`, его длинна равна 0.

Соответственно, условие `if len(sps) == len(s):` не выполняется, и функция просто завершается.